# How to make a single submit button of more then one HTML forms display each table entry as new form in row?

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to get the single submit button of more than one HTML form or maybe I need to improve that multiple HTML forms also (suggestion please).

Screenshots of table and database are below.

[image]

Database Table `tbltest`

**Problem: I need to make single submit button instead of the above multiple submit button  of each row (which is actually a different HTML form ) in which I perform checkbox operation for all rows and then in one click it can update all the rows values in table tbltest but it hurts a lot to  perform each of the checkbox operations and then press each submit**

[image]

Currently, I have done that each HTML form has separate submit button and also each form is a table row displaying the SQL table values and one column i.e. `Status` (which is default set to `0` means `person not selected` and user will see the database entries on the webpage `http://localhost/test1/submitform.php` and change the `0` to `1` means `person selected` based on the values i.e person's information in rows which I display on webpage).

Further on checked the checkbox and submit click the `status` value of that person of that row values get updated in table `tbltest`.

Below is all code files I am using.

File `connection.php`

```
<?php

    // set the timezone first
    if(function_exists('date_default_timezone_set')) {
        date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Kolkata");
    }

    $localhost = 'localhost';
    $user = 'root';
    $password = '';
    $database = 'test';

    $conn = new mysqli($localhost, $user, $password);

    //check connection
    if($conn->connect_error){
        die("Connection Failed".$conn->connect_error);
    }

    //connect database
    mysqli_select_db($conn, $database);

?>
```

File `submitform.php`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Submit Form</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        table{
        border-collapse: separate;
        border-spacing: 0px; /* Apply cell spacing */
    }
    table, th, td{
        border: 1px solid #666;
    }
    table th, table td{
        padding: 5px; /* Apply cell padding */
    }
    button{

        margin-left: 10px;
    }
    .tableheading{
        font-weight: bold;

    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <?php

    include('connection.php');

    echo "<table border='1' cellpadding='2' cellspacing='0'>";

    echo "<div class='tableheading'>";

    echo "<input type='text' value='Id'>";
    echo "<input type='text' value='Name'>";
    echo "<input type='text' value='Age'>";
    echo "<input type='text' value='Gender'>";

    echo "</div>";
    echo "<br>";

    $selectSql = "SELECT * FROM tbltest";

    $result = $conn->query($selectSql);

    // $result = mysqli_execute($selectSql);

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

    echo "<form action='selected.php' method='post'>";

    echo "<input type='text' name='id' value=".$row['Id'].">";

    echo "<input type='text' name='name' value=".$row['Name'].">";
    echo "<input type='text' name='age' value=".$row['Age'].">";
    echo "<input type='text' name='gender' value=".$row['Gender'].">";

    echo "<input type='checkbox' name='yes' value='1'>";
    echo "<label>Selected</select>";
    echo "<input type='checkbox' name='no' value='2'>";
    echo "<label>Not selected</select>";

    echo "<button type='submit' name='selectionsubmit'>Submit</button>";

    echo "</form>";
    echo "<br>";

    }

    echo "</tr>";
    echo "</table>";

    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

File `selected.php`

```
<?php

include('connection.php');

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST'){

    if(isset($_POST['selectionsubmit'])){

            $id = $_POST['id'];

            $name = $_POST['name'];
            $age = $_POST['age'];
            $gender = $_POST['gender'];

            if(isset($_POST['yes'])){
                $select=1;
            }else{
                $select=0;
            }


$updateSql = "UPDATE tbltest SET Status='$select' WHERE Id = '$id'";

            if($conn->query($updateSql) == TRUE){
                echo "Table Updated successfully";
            }
    }
}

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: your html is invalid. The FORM must be entirely within a single table cell (`td`) or the table must be entirely within a form. The same holders true for the other HTML elements (`div`, `br` etc ) that you have there... these are NOT permitted child elements of the table like you have them. As suggested below by @Man87 - have a single form and the table inside

Comment: so what is correct approach according to u, becoz i need all the row values on submit click which can only be fulfilled if each row is a type of html form and on submit click each row values are used to update the status value of table.

Comment: if possible can u update the code files according to you in below answer or suggest some code steps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a spare 1/2 hour so to assist you I put together some changed code to support the comment I made earlier regarding invalid markup and an alternative method of processing the POSTed data.

```
/*

    submitform.php
    --------------
    A single form contains the entire table
    with a single submit button that submits
    the entire form. ALL entries in the form
    will be POSTed to the form's action handler.

*/
echo "
<form action='selected.php' method='post'>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Gender</th>
            <th>Selected</th>
            <th>Not-Selected</th>
        </tr>";

/*

    fetch records from db and add a new table-row
    with 6 table-cells per row.

    The name of the input elements end with []
    to signify an array. When processing the POST
    data you can iterate through the records quite 
    easily.

*/  
$i=1;
$sql = "select `id`,`name`,`age`,`gender`, `status` from `tbltest`";
$result = $conn->query( $sql );
while( $row = mysqli_fetch_array( $result ) ){

    $yes = intval( $row['status'] )==1 ? 'checked' : '';
    $no = intval( $row['status'] )==0 ? 'checked' : '';

    printf("
        <!-- record: %d -->
        <tr>
            <td><input type='text' name='id[]' value='%s' /></td>
            <td><input type='text' name='name[]' value='%s' /></td>
            <td><input type='text' name='age[]' value='%s' /></td>
            <td><input type='text' name='gender[]' value='%s' /></td>
            <!--

                using a pair of checkboxes when only 1 option should be selected
                does not make sense - a radio button is a better option

            -->
            <td><label for='yes'>Yes <input type='radio' name='status_{$i}[]' value='1' %s/></select></td>
            <td><label for='no'>No <input type='radio' name='status_{$i}[]' value='0' %s/></select></td>
        </tr>",
        $i,
        $row['id'],
        $row['name'],
        $row['age'],
        $row['gender'],
        $yes,
        $no
    );

    $i++;
}

echo "
        <tr>
            <td colspan=5>&nbsp;</td>
            <td><input type='submit' /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>";
```

And to process the submission:

```
<?php

    /* selected.php */

    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST' && isset( $_POST['id'], $_POST['name'], $_POST['age'], $_POST['gender'] ) ){

        require 'connection.php';


        $ids = $_POST['id'];
        $names = $_POST['name'];
        $ages = $_POST['age'];
        $genders = $_POST['gender'];



        $sql='UPDATE `tbltest` SET `name`=?, `age`=?, `gender`=?, `status`=? WHERE `id` = ?';
        $stmt=$conn->prepare( $sql );
        if( $stmt ){

            $stmt->bind_param( 'sssii', $name, $age, $gender, $status, $id );

            foreach( $ids as $index => $id ){

                $i=$index+1;

                $name = $names[ $index ];
                $age = $ages[ $index ];
                $gender = $genders[ $index ];
                $status = $_POST[ sprintf( 'status_%d', $i ) ][0];
                $id = $ids[ $index ];

                $stmt->execute();
            }       
        } else {
            exit('error: failed to prepare sql query');
        }
        $stmt->close();

        http_response_code( 200 );
        exit( header( 'Location: submitform.php' ) );
    }



    /* 
        methods other than POST or POST with incorrect fields will receive a 405 error
        ~ Method Not Allowed
    */
    http_response_code( 405 );
    exit();
?>
```

Based upon the following db table

```
create table `tbltest` (
    `id` int(10) unsigned not null auto_increment,
    `name` varchar(50) null default null,
    `age` tinyint(3) unsigned null default null,
    `gender` varchar(6) not null default 'male',
    `status` bit(1) not null default b'0',
    primary key (`id`)
)
engine=innodb;


+--------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field  | Type                | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id     | int(10) unsigned    | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name   | varchar(50)         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| age    | tinyint(3) unsigned | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| gender | varchar(6)          | NO   |     | Male    |                |
| status | bit(1)              | NO   |     | b'0'    |                |
+--------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+


+----+----------+------+--------+--------+
| id | name     | age  | gender | status |
+----+----------+------+--------+--------+
|  1 | Rinku    |   23 | Male   | 1      |
|  2 | Ricky    |   21 | Male   |        |
|  3 | Samantha |   15 | Female | 1      |
+----+----------+------+--------+--------+
```

The above code generates the following looking HTML table

[image: The resultant HTML table]

Comment: Is the page refreshes on making POST request? if possible can we prevent the page refresh and just submit the data?

Comment: use a standard button ( not submit ) and then send an ajax request

Comment: Hi RamRaider, what is below lines doing,  $yes = intval( $row['status'] )==1 ? 'checked' : '';   $no = intval( $row['status'] )==0 ? 'checked' : '';

Comment: These lines are used to re-check the yes/no radio button if the value returned from the db query is either 1 or 0. If you look at the table schema I posed to support my answer you will see that the `status` field is `bit` - will accept 1 or 0 only. In the HTML I assigned values of 1 & 0 to the two radio buttons to correspond to `selected` and `not selected`

Comment: Hi RamRaider, what this line signify,  $status = $_POST[ sprintf( 'status_%d', $i ) ][0]; specially the index 0 as [0].

Comment: why this is done "$i=$index+1;", what is initial value of $index, if it is $id as of entry, then why is incremented when we want value of $i in case we get the value of $status.

Answer (score 0):

Take the form tag outside the while loop and also the sybmit button and then 
take array for all the input types for eg :- for text field name = "id" take name = "id[]". In this you will be able to submit multiple data in form by a single button click

Thanks

Comment: what for checkbox selected, not selected, is this fine that my purpose get solve without any ajax, jquery, or other things

Comment: No need to do ajax but definitely javascript validation you can handle it in the solution i have suggested for multiple checkboxes.Something like the below code :-


$('#someButton').click(function() {
    var values= [];
    $('#MyDiv input:checked').each(function() {
        values.push(this.val);
    });
    // now values contains all of the values of checked checkboxes
    // do something with it
});

Comment: How can i differentiate one input with others if they are in a single form.

Comment: #MyDiv is for each row of table?